# No User Pool when try to request cognito

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I used `amplify add auth` that works fine and then `amplify push`. 
The React website is running without a problem. But when I try to register or login, I get the error `[ERROR] AuthClass - Cannot get the current user because the user pool is missing. Please make sure the Auth module is configured with a valid Cognito User Pool ID`.
But the `aws_user_pools_id` is the same like in the id in the aws console.
Have someone an idea what the problem could be?
thanks ;)

Thats my App.js with no magic...

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <HomeScreen />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Problem was, that you have to add the configure method as well:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import aws_exports from './aws-exports';
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';
Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
```

Comment: I added this to my App.js file

Answer (score 2):

I had faced a similar issue with aws and to overcome I simply created a new user pool after which I was able to log in and register.

Comment: How did you connect the new pool with the project? When I paste the new pool_id into my react project nothing is changing and I am still getting the error.

Comment: Can I check your code, as I cant dig the problem like that?

Comment: Which part do you mean? I did it in the same way like in that official tutorial: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react

Comment: Are you able to retrieve aws pool configuration from aws export ? Console it and check if you are getting that.

Comment: I have just init the Amplify again and add auth. There is a new user pool and the id's in my aws-exports are the same. Could the reason be, that I am using `export default withAuthenticator(App);`?

Comment: Yes, that could be a reason for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following and it worked.

```
amplify push
amplify publish
```

After that, the `No userPool` error went away and I was sent a confirmation code, received it in email, and then used that to confirm my account.  Then I was able to login.

Answer (score 0):

adding value for the region solved the error for me.
default : region: ''
new : region: 'us-east-1'